# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘isempty’

Tags: c

I know this question has been asked elsewhere but reading the already given answers is not helping me. My code is ridiculously simple yet I cannot compile it. I'm writing code to build a stack.

Here is my `stack.h`:

```
#ifndef GUARD
#define GUARD

struct Stack {

    struct Stack* next;
    int           data;
};
extern bool isempty (struct Stack*);

#endif
```

here is my `stack.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "stack.h"

bool isempty (struct Stack* st) {

    return (st == NULL);
}
```

The compiler keeps on complaining about this line:

```
extern bool isempty (struct Stack*);
```

The contents of my `main.c` are irrelevant (for now it just returns 0). Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type `bool` is generally not available in C.

If your compiler supports C99, you can add

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

to make it available, though.

**UPDATE**: Use of C99 is, in my opinion, not exactly pervasive in C programs "in the large", no. Most boolean values, such as function returns, are represented as `int`, which is how it has been solved classically. For arrays, you'd be quite likely to find them represented as bits packed into e.g. `unsigned int`, rather than e.g `bool a[32];`.

But, in an interview context, I think it would be pretty nice for a candidate to write the above without flinching. It was standardized 13 years ago, after all.

Comment: So what is the result then of, for example, comparisons such as `(1 == 2)`? Also, is the inclusion of  `stdbool.h` standard in modern C programs? I'm preparing for a job interview so I don't want to use non-standard stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comparing St and NULL ... result always will be 0 or 1 ... which is not of boolean type in C ..
You should write return type of isempty() as int ...

Comment: There is no problem in converting the expression implicitly to `bool` as long as you can guarantee that all the values fit, which they do, here. To be even more in the vein of the C standard, converting a pointer to `bool` is well defined by it and the comparison to `NULL` or any other null pointer constant is superfluous.